# Cause of iOS ARC over-release crash on XCode 6.4 optimised build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, arm64

The following method crashes due to an early ARC release of inputLower, even though there is still a strong ptr in scope. This is using XCode 6.4 to build for ARM64, and only crashes when -Os optimization is used. Is this an ARC bug, or am I making some kind of ARC logic error?

```
void crasher(NSString * input) {
    NSString * inputLower = [input lowercaseString]; // should be strong ptr
    NSString * inputLower2 = inputLower; // should be a 2nd, independent strong ptr        
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        inputLower2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", inputLower, i++];
        // ERROR: inputLower is released here, so the next iteration will crash
        NSLog(@"%@", inputLower2);
    }
}
```

The crash can be avoided simply by adding a copy, but I've read the ARC rules in detail, and I don't believe this should be required:

```
NSString * inputLower2 = [inputLower copy];
```

If this isn't my fault, I'll file a bug with Apple.

Comment: "Is this an ARC bug, or am I making some kind of ARC logic error?" Neither. It has nothing to do with ARC. It has to do with optimization (as you rightly suggest), and perhaps with the nature of tethering to Xcode. Try running this app _independently_ on a device - that is, _not_ launched from within Xcode, and thus not tethered to Xcode. Now does it crash?

Comment: Yep, it crashes when untethered and not debugging, but only if the optimised build is run. If an unoptimised build is run without debugging, it will not crash. In fact, it was a crash report from the field which alerted me to the problem. It does look to me like the optimization is make pointer aliasing assumptions which conflict with the ARC rules.

Comment: Hang on a sec, I can't reproduce the crash... Give me a sec to try to make it crash.

Comment: Okay, crashed it! Let me see if I can play around with it a bit.

Comment: It's the NSLog inside the `while` loop; something is being optimized away. If you move the NSLog to after the `while` loop you'll see that the loop worked.

Comment: Moreover, I can't reproduce the crash in Xcode 7 (that's why it took me so long to reproduce it; I had to switch specifically to Xcode 6.4). This suggests they know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this sort of thing before. It's not an ARC matter so much as an optimization matter, and NSLog in particular elicits it. In this instance, it's the NSLog inside the while loop that causes the problem; something is being optimized away. If you move the NSLog to *after* the while loop you'll see that the loop worked.

Moreover, I can't reproduce the crash in Xcode 7 (that's why it took me so long to reproduce it; I had to switch specifically to Xcode 6.4). This suggests the Apple folks do know about this.